# Can we define vector space on $\mathbb Z$ over any field?

Tags: linear-algebra

Can we define vector space on $\mathbb Z$ over any field? Intuitively, think that we can not, but how to prove that?

Comment: I assume you want to keep the addition in $\mathbb Z$ intact?

Comment: Yes, we will consider $\mathbb Z$ as an Abelian group

Answer (score 6):

On $\mathbb{Z}$ the *abelian group*, no:

- There does not exist any element with $x+x = 1$, and therefore there cannot exist a vector space structure by a field containing an inverse of $2$, because $\frac{1}{2} \cdot 1$ would have to have that property
- There does not exist any element with $x+x+x = 1$, and therefore there cannot exist a vector space structure by a field containing an inverse of $3$, because $\frac{1}{3} \cdot 1$ would have to have that property

Every field falls into at least one of the two cases.

(by $2$ I mean the element $e+e$ where $e$ is the multiplicative identity of the field, and similarly for $3$)

---

On $\mathbb{Z}$ the *set*, yes. For example, pick your favorite bijection $\theta : \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Q}$. Then we can give $\mathbb{Z}$ the structure of a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$ by defining:

- Addition is given by $x \oplus y = \theta^{-1}(\theta(x) + \theta(y))$
- Scalar multiplication is given by $r \odot x = \theta^{-1}(r \theta(x))$

Comment: "field falls into at least one of the two cases." I think it should be explained in what sense $\mathbb Z_2$ also falls into the second case even though it doesn't have the element $3$.

Comment: @5xum: $3=1$ in $\mathbb{F}_2$. If you want to be technical in that way, note $\mathbb{Q}$ doesn't have the element $3$ either. (it has the equivalence class of $3/1$)

Comment: I know. I just think the answer would benefit from writing that out explicitly...